# Discovering footprints of loaded and unloaded kernel mode drivers

Tags: windows, windows-kernel, nt

Background: There are vulnerable kernel mode drivers for Windows systems, which can be loaded into the system for various purposes. Loaded kernel mode drivers leave traces in the system. Anti-cheat software for video games, for example, look for vulnerable driver traces in various parts of the system because they are used for cheating. The logic used by anti-cheat software could perhaps be (or were already) used by anti-rootkit tools or rootkits themselves.

I am wondering where traces are left after drivers are loaded and then unloaded. From my research, I found these two places in Windows NT kernel, where unloaded drivers leave traces:

1. PiDDBCacheTable
2. MmUnloadedDrivers

(Just to let you know, those are undocumented data structures)
Where else could they leave traces? Is it possible for me to learn it without reverse-engineering the Windows kernel by myself?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, `ExpCovUnloadedDrivers` is another function to detect unloaded drivers. But as far as I know, only drivers that use code coverage get added to this list.